# FB Login Callback crashing for Testflight Users

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, openurl

I am using Facebook's SDK for logging into my app. I have no issues using it myself, but when my Testflight users login, the app crashes when the app returns from the Facebook app. I've also been told the app crashes when clicking open from inside the Testflight app which leads me to believe it has to do with this code below. It's hard to know for sure because Testflight crash logs are very inconsistent and I haven't received any yet...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Here's the crash log (truncated last couple of lines due to character limit):

```
{"app_name":"Dozmia","app_cohort":"2|date=1435078800000&sf=143441&tid=40a1449018deaf3d138ed8487cd1651d98b96a10f31bde5db4e9f0f5027bf585","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"57799f65-08a7-353c-8e87-fee4f3c36ee9","adam_id":1004247210,"build_version":"17","bundleID":"com.dylanreich.Dozmia","share_with_app_devs":true,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 8.3 (12F70)","is_beta":true,"name":"Dozmia"}
Incident Identifier: 4D000AD7-D84A-4E07-97F5-9FD26D36DEC5
Beta Identifier:     B210028C-BF7C-4692-B327-C024F4AE801A
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Dozmia [422]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Dozmia
Identifier:          com.dylanreich.Dozmia
Version:             17 (1.0)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-23 13:07:32.623 -0400
Launch Time:         2015-06-23 13:07:29.536 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100307794
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100307794 0x100210000 + 1013652
1   Dozmia                          0x00000001000c61e0 0x100094000 + 205280
2   Dozmia                          0x00000001000c3e84 0x100094000 + 196228
3   Dozmia                          0x00000001000c3f24 0x100094000 + 196388
4   UIKit                           0x000000018a2ccc80 0x18a2bc000 + 68736
5   UIKit                           0x000000018a2cc990 0x18a2bc000 + 67984
6   UIKit                           0x000000018a46f258 0x18a2bc000 + 1782360
7   UIKit                           0x000000018a381eec 0x18a2bc000 + 810732
8   UIKit                           0x000000018a381cb8 0x18a2bc000 + 810168
9   UIKit                           0x000000018a381c38 0x18a2bc000 + 810040
10  UIKit                           0x000000018a2c975c 0x18a2bc000 + 55132
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c11e18 0x189c04000 + 56856
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c0c880 0x189c04000 + 34944
13  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c0c724 0x189c04000 + 34596
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c0beb8 0x189c04000 + 32440
15  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c0bc38 0x189c04000 + 31800
16  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189c05360 0x189c04000 + 4960
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001858442a0 0x185764000 + 918176
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018584122c 0x185764000 + 905772
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018584160c 0x185764000 + 906764
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018576d2d0 0x185764000 + 37584
21  GraphicsServices                0x000000018ef836f8 0x18ef78000 + 46840
22  UIKit                           0x000000018a332fa8 0x18a2bc000 + 487336
23  Dozmia                          0x00000001000abd50 0x100094000 + 97616
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019772ea04 0x19772c000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019782cc24 0x19782c000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197711e6c 0x197700000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197703998 0x197700000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 6 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019782ce0c 0x19782c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019782cc84 0x19782c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185843720 0x185764000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185841674 0x185764000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018576d2d0 0x185764000 + 37584
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001841e902c 0x1841d0000 + 102444
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001841dba0c 0x1841d0000 + 47628
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3dc4 0x1978e0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3d20 0x1978e0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0ef4 0x1978e0000 + 3828

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019782ce0c 0x19782c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019782cc84 0x19782c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185843720 0x185764000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185841674 0x185764000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018576d2d0 0x185764000 + 37584
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018524e890 0x1851b0000 + 649360
6   Foundation                      0x000000018678ddb4 0x186698000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3dc4 0x1978e0000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3d20 0x1978e0000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0ef4 0x1978e0000 + 3828

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847498 0x19782c000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185849124 0x185764000 + 938276
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3dc4 0x1978e0000 + 15812
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e3d20 0x1978e0000 + 15648
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0ef4 0x1978e0000 + 3828

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197847c78 0x19782c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e12d8 0x1978e0000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001978e0eec 0x1978e0000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100208380   x1: 0x00000001700f4280   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000197881a74
    x4: 0x000000016fd67e38   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x00000001700f4300   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000100204000  x11: 0x00000000005c03d0
   x12: 0x706172776e752065  x13: 0x206e6120676e6970  x14: 0x6c616e6f6974704f  x15: 0x000a65756c617620
   x16: 0x00000001978d9a50  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000013cd2cdd0
   x20: 0x00000001989b7740  x21: 0x0000000000000008  x22: 0x000000018aad5078  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x000000018aac9533  x25: 0x000000016fd69358  x26: 0x000000016fd69398  x27: 0x000000019b7060a8
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fd67f20   lr: 0x0000000100307794
    sp: 0x000000016fd67f10   pc: 0x0000000100307794 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x100094000 - 0x10018ffff Dozmia arm64  <57799f6508a7353c8e87fee4f3c36ee9> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Dozmia
0x1001ec000 - 0x1001f3fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib arm64  <07d61bd9ac4f3e97ad164e6f98c1d94b> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
0x100210000 - 0x1003bbfff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <ee2e8ba2967334a5b6bc6f1abb009365> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x100afc000 - 0x100b03fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <636675bb8e263854a5b7430b14e899b3> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x100b30000 - 0x100b37fff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64  <c11adac593eb3d4797a3d29862a48f48> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
0x100b58000 - 0x100b63fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <211b011d7fd230a7a765de8561377a43> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100ba8000 - 0x100baffff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <0bb53b8fe87f3c9286fcfe0a237d3db1> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x100bc0000 - 0x100bc7fff libswiftCoreLocation.dylib arm64  <f1da5f0258283ec6a974ad7f8031eaf8> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
0x100be8000 - 0x100beffff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <9ced57d84355350fa2cee4e27cbb469e> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x100c20000 - 0x100c27fff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <6fbefc3070763dc8bc2a1d56b219b738> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x100c64000 - 0x100c6bfff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <b7d82093829230ddbf06ec5448d006c4> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x100c90000 - 0x100cbffff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <b75ec9e7c0ed39748dfdce9f5feb96e5> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x100d90000 - 0x100d97fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <002edc04a9a637898c43872f1385ffcb> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x100dc4000 - 0x100dcbfff libswiftSecurity.dylib arm64  <be67db1070653f47983603cedfa3c012> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib
0x100dec000 - 0x100df3fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <c53275f2b02b381e8b9718e4f988944d> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/07B97668-EAC7-4ECE-84DA-8888A3BF0E9F/Dozmia.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x1200a0000 - 0x1200c7fff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld
0x184038000 - 0x1841ccfff AVFoundation arm64  <c69cb19d6db0339bbfb4c18fa7f4f26c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x1841d0000 - 0x184234fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <fdd31b28c0ec3f76b8f0fa9a057e43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x184278000 - 0x184278fff Accelerate arm64  <a2161063fee1315193bc488d0354f43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184290000 - 0x1844affff vImage arm64  <74eb7b77dbcd321db86e784be9353a08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1844b0000 - 0x184557fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <56e8b79c2c03379dad45fe2ea1a4052f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184558000 - 0x1848d2fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <fd491ae19b12315babb621650a0eef76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1848d4000 - 0x1848e9fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <9307063a5e1833abbb857a9ec4c5369e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1848ec000 - 0x184954fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <d4d2b4a941213e2b81f3ddafd6b8a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x184958000 - 0x18497bfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <92a0dd635be43dfe8c128c888ef37c0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18497c000 - 0x18497cfff vecLib arm64  <9248f57f1d8430219a810aa93254f157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x184980000 - 0x1849affff Accounts arm64  <4199851056d4376aa4d8668b83c85454> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1849b0000 - 0x1849b0fff AdSupport arm64  <f172a17bdc2e3bd19b952a69e0021450> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x184d50000 - 0x185010fff AudioToolbox arm64  <760c2dc59fa13660a769cc1b052d41e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x1851b0000 - 0x1853c3fff CFNetwork arm64  <df5535d1633f375aa889f755db0a93b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x185464000 - 0x1854c9fff CoreAudio arm64  <b85ca2cdb29639ccb5f6405baf597027> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1854f0000 - 0x185511fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <fbd7cbc4b2533ea38844bf98757ce58d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x185514000 - 0x185760fff CoreData arm64  <af13d4e830e13607b745fe57f90e5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x185764000 - 0x185ac2fff CoreFoundation arm64  <6548b13bef1f3f958d96266f7c4c44e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x185ac4000 - 0x185c26fff CoreGraphics arm64  <92162d42d08d357ab66302a38d724828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x185c7c000 - 0x185c7efff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <8f40b7d9b97b344f9c7a5a0b79bdc2b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x185c80000 - 0x185c8bfff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <a40d7bdbbe6c3317bcf4c20c085df848> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x185e80000 - 0x185e9efff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <975284709e51353690ec8a651b43c1db> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x185ea0000 - 0x185fd2fff CoreImage arm64  <d7a2122dc8173803bc220fde3cfebfdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x185fd4000 - 0x186032fff CoreLocation arm64  <a166ad7f12f93406b54ae6a170fb38ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x18606c000 - 0x18612ffff CoreMedia arm64  <403a9798401c3b70a207e0e236454c0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x186130000 - 0x18621efff CoreMotion arm64  <61338e072f2a385ab4e315975f23eea2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x186220000 - 0x186291fff CoreTelephony arm64  <450440ee68593b8e9c951cdf838264f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x186294000 - 0x18639cfff CoreText arm64  <4a9633cee0393585a98fcf07410e0828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1863a0000 - 0x1863bdfff CoreVideo arm64  <217e5b69f6d03f8893f01de3e40915a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x186698000 - 0x1868f0fff Foundation arm64  <509b484fb7b634b19673d50296d8278f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x186a38000 - 0x186aa3fff IOKit arm64  <311bed1f2b893195b8c0564d8925bfa2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x186aa4000 - 0x186d47fff ImageIO arm64  <7d3c81746f2c3f1488b3efc633d21633> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x186d48000 - 0x1871e9fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <1ad0ed311f3e3897bac70f3388fc05be> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x187b24000 - 0x187b2afff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4e3e82a2b09a38fcbf01843f97d5e604> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x187b2c000 - 0x187d4ffff MediaPlayer arm64  <fb0500c5695c36b5b54865f533cc899e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x187d50000 - 0x18816efff MediaToolbox arm64  <c2103a7dd16e3f67abfe898b039061e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x188248000 - 0x1882c0fff Metal arm64  <eb54636e26cd3dee870fa5e4fb708fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x1882c4000 - 0x188375fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <daa61b358c17365792c20df791224e26> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x1895f0000 - 0x1895fafff OpenGLES arm64  <8824bb82d43937a9b0aa3870ece35772> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x189600000 - 0x189601fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <34760639fb2331dcaa229ba0e418c1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x189604000 - 0x189607fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6f967504d5937d59223598de12969ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x189608000 - 0x18960cfff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <30969b8fde9f36c4a6a0293c03e74e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x189610000 - 0x18961afff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <5942ea8060c63e86b3ffbfb76b061276> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18961c000 - 0x189667fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <3e46a6b44be93e5689e4851c76b2db04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x189c04000 - 0x189d96fff QuartzCore arm64  <e47923f08f343c3e98e77f22f674f234> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18a01c000 - 0x18a070fff Security arm64  <80b60ba1feba39afb6686e342398cce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18a244000 - 0x18a2b7fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <633d8a8abeaf3abda9b0401146f2b668> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x18a2bc000 - 0x18ac3cfff UIKit arm64  <f67965f71974303e90cfaed997ae36a3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18ac40000 - 0x18acb9fff VideoToolbox arm64  <1468c96c3448370bbb407644bedbb368> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18b5c4000 - 0x18b5c9fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <cfa106cd07b430a6959f9127a6c3363a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18b7cc000 - 0x18b7cffff AirPlaySupport arm64  <9379098c9eed33088c7096882eec570d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x18ba24000 - 0x18ba6cfff AppSupport arm64  <d088c6263b4932aebd9dcf2a14aadef2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18bbdc000 - 0x18bc28fff AppleJPEG arm64  <621fe1223e9038a09023dd6c558ce423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18bc54000 - 0x18bc5dfff AppleSRP arm64  <8f0cacbeabdf39b3815a72e7ec9e8668> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x18bc70000 - 0x18bc7bfff AssertionServices arm64  <e0f182c7fdcd34a1a4acfe0bd4c7eae3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18bc7c000 - 0x18bc99fff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <e28e74aed7103573b9416e016525ac04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x18bd18000 - 0x18bd1bfff BTLEAudioController arm64  <ea2ff306f28638ca8bc7a4f02d3c8f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x18bd1c000 - 0x18bd38fff BackBoardServices arm64  <ff372ac34d6430829a97778caad5bdf4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18bd40000 - 0x18bd7dfff BaseBoard arm64  <ab16c3464cfb3319bf31202639bb4a90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18c0a8000 - 0x18c0b2fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <0f8d341d0a8f3828b9485b189d04e126> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x18c0c0000 - 0x18c20cfff Celestial arm64  <0b8842c85d7139848f5e049e8e784c47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18c9d0000 - 0x18c9e2fff CommonUtilities arm64  <cf917a1cdf503940a9879dda3ea7eae4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18cad4000 - 0x18cad9fff ConstantClasses arm64  <b1cc336c6ea1319f8131623918110a89> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18cb1c000 - 0x18cb24fff CoreAUC arm64  <ac7f4428bde93a379e4710ff07f8cd82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18cbc4000 - 0x18cbecfff CoreDuet arm64  <2325864ac79931d08384cad9a5c2378c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x18cbf8000 - 0x18cc0bfff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <8e9b82e37ab1398fb75be0114863b188> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x18cc14000 - 0x18cc16fff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <9a52d10bde253ae196a436618e6245af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18d0bc000 - 0x18d0e0fff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <c35ab32d16e839e5bd3a2d4357cd512b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x18d348000 - 0x18d3dcfff CoreUI arm64  <8e5f6e68de253eb98752939e94219aa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18d3e0000 - 0x18d47afff CoreUtils arm64  <835930892f3f3c28823421061c40dad7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18d47c000 - 0x18d482fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <939d8e00b1a8388eaf6721fe6fed8d07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18d484000 - 0x18d48afff DAAPKit arm64  <996db669e80833e0a44db31c6e094693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18d7bc000 - 0x18d7c3fff DataMigration arm64  <ac8e9c98ebaf3b3facc8a35d4a5f662d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18d7e4000 - 0x18d804fff DictionaryServices arm64  <d911eb3e1549338d8a3da77f3cf030ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18d82c000 - 0x18d852fff EAP8021X arm64  <6201a1545ea735eaa654e6c4f19fce9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18d9c4000 - 0x18ddf1fff FaceCore arm64  <6c9c849bf1173e1892729204b96c95bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18de78000 - 0x18de78fff FontServices arm64  <9d2ca68913c53fef976aabcdb3f2bb7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18de7c000 - 0x18df5cfff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <3e696fd5c611305eaee6bad27362f029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18df60000 - 0x18df6ffff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <c98491fefd2a34f5a1a5fab3cce3d478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x18e07c000 - 0x18e09cfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <06e8a3da46443f858df92288b8b009bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18ec60000 - 0x18ef75fff GeoServices arm64  <624b0528e79e3bd78cf8e4ca477e207b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x18ef78000 - 0x18ef8bfff GraphicsServices arm64  <75b91070a0e7388fb904347f318b8cc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18f260000 - 0x18f2fafff HomeSharing arm64  <9d9df9ed1dc53162a89400f3c5a786df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x18f660000 - 0x18f667fff IOAccelerator arm64  <95ab3e3274d630779faccf8902ddc494> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18f66c000 - 0x18f672fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <079c9947522f331b8837714ca08e0966> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x18f674000 - 0x18f67afff IOSurface arm64  <202149d941b339f1a765e48058a523ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18f67c000 - 0x18f67efff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <9aaea96dbea43a648fa78e7f43f769cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18f9ec000 - 0x18fa31fff LanguageModeling arm64  <f484305f34db38e7be02f5cd0b37404b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x18fc2c000 - 0x18fceafff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <b8ba68326c7030c1803e9f01edcefe02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x18fd00000 - 0x18fd84fff MediaControlSender arm64  <efb209af426c3d2bb592c4e8f2648a27> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x18fe38000 - 0x18fe50fff MediaRemote arm64  <29897add26cf34f7b92dc012ed32f883> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x18fe54000 - 0x18fe69fff MediaServices arm64  <98515a962b2f335da9efb5f14931c42f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaServices.framework/MediaServices
0x190024000 - 0x190033fff MobileAsset arm64  <b09857caa4663e268cbf77652e40c7df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x1900a0000 - 0x1900a9fff MobileInstallation arm64  <096c77b57b62337bb756b2b347fb0768> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x1900ac000 - 0x1900bbfff MobileKeyBag arm64  <0e6f9d62dfe23cbca54b4d1a14f76149> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1900f8000 - 0x1900fbfff MobileSystemServices arm64  <54153419dcaa356fb42fd86b712a4cf2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x190124000 - 0x190135fff MobileWiFi arm64  <b033fc6a7d7b39debe0d81296dce51e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x19018c000 - 0x190394fff MusicLibrary arm64  <8febe3b9c72a311f9cf0f8a95e52b821> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x1905cc000 - 0x1905d2fff Netrb arm64  <28eb6839c8f63101816697fa19770689> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x1905d4000 - 0x1905dbfff NetworkStatistics arm64  <b120e0e7ff6d36889b917c7ca2e5f978> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x190608000 - 0x19060bfff OAuth arm64  <e8987386b74a365582fa85fef51bc127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x190dd4000 - 0x190e22fff OpenCL arm64  <9ad1144d2c4333b980276e2c4e6ac4fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x190fa0000 - 0x190fc9fff PersistentConnection arm64  <6723595bce1937c3a45fbb85baff8c55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x191460000 - 0x1914adfff PhysicsKit arm64  <6a97907da3523632b9e4848047aa8f4a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x1914cc000 - 0x1914d4fff PowerLog arm64  <e938cd724d08330995b5f601f8dd14f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x19184c000 - 0x19190dfff ProofReader arm64  <5d4f70ce92443a24b01e5c2186abfb15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x191940000 - 0x19194efff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <479705f12ac2303b931994a7b06663bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x191990000 - 0x191a0efff Quagga arm64  <66a25218aec23c18b9a18d8f810c5258> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x19200c000 - 0x19202cfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <c2866d40ee023cf9bb04fd7e58d20be2>
```

Comment: Do you have any crash logs at all? That would really help to see where the exception is originating.

Comment: I updated the question with the crash log.

Comment: I created a "bypass Facebook" button for my test user to just send them to the next view controller without logging in, and they still got the same crash, so Facebook may be unrelated.